# Optimize the Performance of ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY..)

Tags: sql

I am using 
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.EmpID , dimdt.YEAR_NUMBER, dimdt.MONTH_OF_YEAR_NUMBER ORDER BY dimdt.Date DESC) row_number
, field1
.field2 .. ec
my ft table has millions of row. I can get the result (month end most recent records of each employee) what I want but it is very slow rather extremely slow. Is there any alternative or a way to optimize the performance?

thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You'll need to tag your question with your database vendor (sql server, oracle, etc), add the whole query, and add some sample data to get any semblance of a real answer.  You can simplify the query and spoof data for the question but be sure you don't remove any important stuff (complicated `where` filters, ordering, etc) that could also be causing performance problems.  `ROW_NUMBER` itself is quite fast, so it's hard to believe that it's your actual issue, and there isn't anything to blindly suggest in place of it.

Answer (score 1):

For this expression:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.EmpID , dimdt.YEAR_NUMBER, dimdt.MONTH_OF_YEAR_NUMBER ORDER BY dimdt.Date DESC)
```

There is not much you can do.  The columns are from different tables.

Even phrasing the logic differently would have the same issue -- but you can consider asking a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and the full query you want to optimize.

Comment: I am using Sql-Server 2016. I have a very big query. But I just using 2 tables fact joining with dimdate  (only one join) to get few fields to test it's performance.